# Using Shape at runtime in android

Tags: android

I want to do follwing thing from JAVA code . How can i do it ?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
<solid android:color="#FFFddd"/>
<padding android:left="7dp" android:top="13dp" 
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="17dp" /> 
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
```

Comment: color changed at runtime so i need to do it .

Answer (score 1):

the corresponding java class is the **ShapeDrawable()**

a good way to find out how xml layouts are defined programmatically is to define the layout first as xml and then inflate it. There you can debug it inside the debugger and look what classes/propertys are set.

great methods for this getChild, getParent, getShapeXXX.

Comment: I used ShapeDrawable() but i am able to set corners with it. How can i set corner and stroke ?

Comment: How can i debug it? Where can i have debugger from ?

Comment: use the eclipse default debugger, the icon with the bug on it ;)

Comment: I could not get you . I just open eclipse debugger. What is next to do ?